# Propel 1.6 Formatter

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, propel

Is there any way I can set a formatter on models that will convert negative numbers to positive numbers for all numeric fields in the model? I started out by trying to make a propel formatter but I'm not sure what code should go in format and formatOne. I have the following code.

```
class NegativeFormatter extends PropelFormatter
{
  public function format(PropelPDO $stmt)
  {
    parent::format($stmt);
  }

  public function formatOne(PropelPDO $stmt)
  {
    parent::formatOne($stmt);
  }

  public function isObjectFormatter()
  {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just doing it manually for now when doing the calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [absolute value](http://php.net/abs) function.

Comment: I am already doing that for a few of the fields...but I would have to do that for all 30 or so fields

Comment: Ah, I thought you meant you didn't know how to achieve the modification of the numeric value :P I'm not familiar with Propel, so you'll have to keep searching. Good luck!

Comment: Yeah. Haven't found anything yet except for the propel documentation about formatters